# C# XML deserialized. How to get a few elements from next line?

Tags: c#, xml

```
        if (slowo == "Sprzedawca")
        {
            List<OcrRes.word> temp = result.Words.Where(item => item.value.Contains(slowo)).ToList();
            int line = int.Parse(temp.First().line);



            Console.Write(line);
        }
```

I need to view next line elements where line is an atribute of element. How to get them ?
elements looks like that :
`<w line="9" blanks="0" fontIndex="0" formating="0" confidence="79,56706" pointSize="0" r="90,351,172,30" id="21">Sprzedawca</w>`

Comment: //<w line="9" blanks="0" fontIndex="0" formating="0" confidence="79,56706" pointSize="0" r="90,351,172,30" id="21">Sprzedawca</w>

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong. You are given an XML and somewhere there there is a collection of `w` elements. What you want is to get this collection and for each element `w` extract its attributes, right? If this is the case, below is how you can do it:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(input);
var wElements = xml.Root.DescendantsAndSelf("w");

foreach (var w in wElements)
{
    // extract attribute values like this
    var confidence = w.Attribute("confidence").Value;

    Console.WriteLine(confidence); // prints 79,56706
}
```

The code above basically gets all elements `w` and enumerates them. You would want to check `xml.Root` for null.

Answer (score 0):

http://wklej.org/id/2845120/

i have code like that, and xml like that : http://wklej.org/id/2845122/

and i need to get get in console next elements from line = 10 to get sentence :
Przedsiębiorstwo Handlowo usługowe CENIE" Demo

Comment: don't know how to end my if to compile that. I'm begginer